# Set PHP variable to XML value?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, rss

I want to use XML in PHP. Till now I use this PHP (for a little 'rss reader'):

```
<?php

$items = 25;
$rss     = simplexml_load_file('rss.xml');

echo "<h1>{$rss->channel->title}</h1>\n";

for($i=0;$i<$items;$i+=1)
   {  
   echo "<div class=\"channel\"><a href=\"{$rss->channel->item[$i]->link}\" target=\"_blank\">{$rss->channel->item[$i]->title}</a></div>\n";
   echo "<div class=\"description\">{$rss->channel->item[$i]->description}</div><br>\n";
   }

?>
```

I'm using this to get a value from the XML: `{$rss->channel->item[$i]->link}`.
But I want to set a PHP value called `$link` to this value.

I tried something like `$link = $rss->channel->item[$i]->link`, but that doesn't work. So how can I set the PHP variable `$link` to the value in the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what "does not work" means exactly. So I'll make a guess here:

```
$link = (string)$rss->channel->item[$i]->link;
```